# In jquery when click button toggle DIV

Tags: jquery

Hi I have question about jquery.
I have div lists and When click each buttons, DIV need to animate. 
The question is  when I click the button, all DIV moving together.

How to change the code?

```
$('.list_const a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).children('button').toggleClass('on');

        if (! $('button').hasClass('on')) { 
            $('button .ico').animate({
                left: '12px'
            }, 500);
        } else { 
            $('button .ico').animate({
                left: '60'
            }, 500);
        }

    });
```

Comment: you are using $('button'), so all the buttons will be animated

Comment: It would be helpful to see your HTML but you can try changing `$('button .ico').animate({` to `$(this).children('button').find('.ico').animate({`. Currently your animation is applying to all `.ico` elements inside all `buttons`.

Comment: @Álvaro Touzón   ok.. then how to make them seperately?

Comment: Posting your html means you will get fast answers

Comment: @ WizardCoder  Thank you  solved the problem  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('.list_const a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).children('button').toggleClass('on');

        if (!  $(this).children('button').hasClass('on')) { 
           $(this).children('button .ico').animate({
                left: '12px'
            }, 500);
        } else { 
          $(this).children('button .ico').animate({
                left: '60'
            }, 500);
        }

    });
```